# JavaScript 1.7 made my code not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works in Jfiddle when the language is javascript but not when it's javascript 1.7. It doesn't put anything in the textbox on the actual website either. It should take user inputs and return a number. I'm new to web development so any help would be great.

```js
$('#teambtn').click(function() {

var Domain = $("#domain option:selected").val();
var Mobile = $("#Mobile option:selected").val();
var Pages = document.getElementById("pages").value;
Domain = Domain * 1;
Mobile = Mobile * 1;
Pages = Pages * 1;
var Result = ((10 + (Pages*5)) * Mobile) + Domain;
Result = Result + '';
$('textarea#team').text(Result);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Oktoberfest</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no" />
  <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body class="" id="top">
  <div class="main">
<!--==============================header=================================-->
  <header>
   
  
    <div class="menu_block ">
     
       <div id="navigation">
       <nav class="horizontal-nav full-width horizontalNav-notprocessed">
        
          <center>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/JVMX4YH.png"/>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
         <a href="index-1.html">About</a>
         <a href="index-2.html">Hire Us</a>
         <a href="index-3.html">Price Esimator</a>
         <!--<a href="index-4.html">Photos</a>-->
         <!--<a href="index-5.html">Testimonials</a>-->
         <a href="index-6.html">Resources</a>
            <a href="index-7.html">Tutorials</a>
        </center>
        
       </nav>
       </div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
   
   
    <div class="container_12">
     
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   </header>
<!--==============================Content=================================-->
  <br><br><br>
   <div class="content">
    <div class="container_12">
$('#teambtn').click(function() {

var Domain = $("#domain option:selected").val();
var Mobile = $("#Mobile option:selected").val();
var Pages = document.getElementById("pages").value;;
Domain = Domain * 1
Mobile = Mobile * 1
Pages = Pages * 1
var Result = ((10 + (Pages*5)) * Mobile) + Domain;
Result = Result + ''
$('textarea#team').text(Result);
});
</script>  
            
<center>
Domain Suffix&nbsp;
        <select id="domain">
                <option value = "10">.com</option>
                <option value = "10">.org</option>
                <option value = "7.5">.net</option>
                <option value = "0">.tk or another domain</option>
             
    </select>       <br />    <br/>
    Do you want a mobile version of your site.&nbsp;
    <select id="Mobile">
                <option value = "1">No</option>
                <option value="1.5">Yes</option>    
    </select>

<br /><br />
            How many Pages will your site have (imput a whole number) :&nbsp;<input type="text" name="hp evs"id='pages' size="5" value ="1">

<br /><br />
            <textarea id=team cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
            <div class="mybutton" id="mybutton">
            <button id="teambtn" size="30" >Export</button>
      
  <br /> 
    <br /> 
      <br /> 
        <br /> 
          <br /> 
            <br /> 
              <br /> 
                <br /> 
                  <br /> 
                    <br /> 



                    </div>   
        
    </center></div></div></div>
 
          
 
<!--==============================footer=================================-->
     <footer>Contact Us - (847)967-1184 Email - frankkmusic@gmail.com | <a href="https://github.com/Kingdiepie/Frankkmusic/blob/master/LICENSE">LICENSE</a><br><a href="https://www.gigmasters.com/german-band/frank-k--company">Gigmaster</a>|<a href="https://www.gigsalad.com/frank_k_company_morton_grove">Gigsalad</a>|<a href="https://www.facebook.com/FrankKDuoCompany">Facebook</a></footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

`enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/67y57kyb/1/

Comment: You included jQuery twice!

Comment: You included the same library twice in that code. That is a problem. Remove the second jquery include.

Comment: Oh I see, I'll see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: That didn't make a difference.

Comment: It works in the provided JSFiddle. What particular error you have got in console?

Comment: switch the language in the Jfiddle to 1.7 and it fails to work (not sure if that matters). I Don't get any errors in the console so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Do you guys see anything wrong with my JS?